# How to sync Parse channels with our API to serve push notifications correctly

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, push-notification

We use Parse to handle push notifications for our mobile apps, and we´re having a hard time figuring out how we can make sure that user notification preferences saved on our database are in sync with channels on Parse.

We developed a soccer scores app, where users follow their favorite teams to get push notifications when those teams score. We save those teams in both our database (in order to serve our API) and in parse, and most of the time that´s fine, but some times, something will get written on one side and not in the other, causing obvious issues with push notifications. So we are looking for a way of syncing the information, and we´re wondering: what´s a good way of approaching this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Webhooks.  No idea what your own server looks like, but I'm sure you can add a webhook there.  But you could absolutely put that in the before save trigger for Installation objects. If the channels key is dirty, trigger a the save on your own server.  Then, only ever update the parse installation's channels when you want to update both.

Vice versa if you've got the equivalent of a before save trigger on your own server. Or just only update this via a singular cloud function that updates your own db + the parse db.

The before save trigger in parse sounds like the simplest and most reliable without knowing your server setup, though.

Comment: Hey @Jake, do you by any chance do freelance work? Someone else perhaps reading this with Parse.com experience?

Comment: Add your e-mail to your profile and I'll reach out.

Comment: Done. Added to about me section.